# Updating Red5 SharedObject closing stream

Tags: apache-flex, video-streaming, rtmp, red5, shared-objects

I'm trying to create a voice conference room with all users can speak and use the mic. But as an Admin, I should have the privilege to mute any user. So, I add to the user an attribute for the mic which will be check in client side and enable/disable user's mic accordingly. The server side code looks like:

```
String identifier;
String userID;
private int _gId  = 1;
private Map<String,Object> newUser;
@Override
public boolean appConnect(IConnection conn, Object[] params) {

    identifier = (String)params[1];
    userID = (String)params[0];
    int _globalUserId = _gId++;

    conn.getClient().setAttribute("id", _globalUserId);

    newUser = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    newUser.put("identifier", (String)params[0]);
    newUser.put("mic", 1); //mic value to be checked in client side
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean roomJoin(IClient client, IScope scope) {
    ISharedObject so = getSharedObject(scope, "users_so");
    so.setAttribute(userID,newUser);

    return true;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void muteUser(String userID){
    IScope scope = Red5.getConnectionLocal().getScope();
    ISharedObject so = getSharedObject(scope, "users_so");
    Map<String,Object> user= new HashMap<String,Object>();
    user = (Map<String, Object>) so.getAttribute(userID);
    if(user != null){
    user.put("mic", 0);
    so.beginUpdate();
    boolean removed = so.removeAttribute(userID);
    boolean updated = so.setAttribute(userID,user);
    so.endUpdate();
    log.info("Mic: " + user.get("mic"));
    log.info("Removed: " + removed);
    log.info("Updated: " + updated);
    }

  }
```

The problem arises when I try to call the muteUser method. Red5 says that the stream is closed. I think this happens when I remove the attribute of the user and added it again but I couldn't find another way to update the sharedObject's mic value.

Does any one have a better idea to update a sharedObject without losing stream?

Answer (score 0):

The SO that you're requesting doesn't work like a user map that it would appear you think it does in your example. I would suggest storing a map in the SO and then do a get / add to the map; the map in this case being shared, so you'd have to make it thread-safe; I'd use a ConcurrentMap there like so:

```
ISharedObject so = getSharedObject(scope, "users_so");
if (so == null) {
  // make sure your so exists
}
so.beginUpdate();
ConcurrentMap<String, Object> users = (ConcurrentMap<String, Object>) so.getAttribute("users");
if (users == null) {
  users = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();
  so.setAttribute("users" users);
}
Object user = users.get(userID);
user.put("mic", 0);
so.endUpdate();
```

Comment: That's very interesting, I've never thought of ConcurrentHashMap. I will try make use of it and back to you with results